# Why UITableView on the device smaller than in IB

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder

When I create my UI in IB I can't do it right because `UITableView` height not equals its height on the device.

I don't understand why?

Example:
http://img35.imageshack.us/i/20110401111017.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the view is being resized when it is pushed on the navigation stack. You can fix this several ways. The best thing to do it setup your nib so it matches the displayed size. You can also remove te autoresize flags from the UITableView. Finally you could programmatically resize the view inside of the view controller's viewWillShow:(BOOL)animated.